# How do I deploy a simple Google App Script Library to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

I created a Google App Script named 'MySimpleSharedCode' with the following code:

```
var MySimpleSharedCode = MySimpleSharedCode || {};

MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello = function() {
  return "hello from MySimpleSharedCode";
}

function sayHello2() {
  var result = MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello();
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

I deployed this script as a Library.

Then created a new Google App Script named 'BorrowerCode'. Added the 'MySimpleSharedCode' library and then following code:

```
function sayHello3() {
  var result = MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello();
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

Now when I run sayHello2() in 'MySimpleSharedCode' I see in the logs what I would expect:

```
hello from MySimpleSharedCode
```

But when I run sayHello3() in 'BorrowerCode' I get an error

```
TypeError: MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello is not a function
sayHello3   @ Code.gs:2
```

What am I doing wrong?

In the screenshot above, looks like the library got added. But somehow I'm not able to access the code in the library?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected answer, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not your expected answer, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, when `MySimpleSharedCode` is installed in `BorrowerCode` as a library of identification of `MySimpleSharedCode`, `MySimpleSharedCode` has the objects of `MySimpleSharedCode` and `sayHello2`.

In your following sample script of `BorrowerCode`,

```js
function sayHello3() {
  var result = MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello();
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

`MySimpleSharedCode` has no object of `sayHello()`. By this, such an error occurs. If you want to run the function of `sayHello` of `MySimpleSharedCode` from `BorrowerCode`, please modify it as follows.

```js
function sayHello3() {
  var result = MySimpleSharedCode.MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello();
  console.log(result); // hello from MySimpleSharedCode
  return result;
}
```

For example, if you want to call `sayHello` using `MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello()` from `BorrowerCode`, how about the following modification?

##### `MySimpleSharedCode`

```js
var MySimpleSharedCode = MySimpleSharedCode || {};

var sayHello = function () {
  return "hello from MySimpleSharedCode";
};

MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello = sayHello;

function sayHello2() {
  var result = MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello();
  console.log(result);
}
```

##### `BorrowerCode`

```js
function sayHello3() {
  var result = MySimpleSharedCode.sayHello();
  console.log(result);
}
```

- By this modification, when `sayHello2()` is run at `MySimpleSharedCode`, `hello from MySimpleSharedCode` is shown. And, when `sayHello3()` is run at `BorrowerCode`, `hello from MySimpleSharedCode` is shown.

#### Reference:

- [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)